# Fin the greatest and least value of $(4\sin θ-6\cos θ)^2-3$ where $0°<θ<90°$

Tags: trigonometry

This question I found the tan by doing 4^2/6^2 and put it in the form of 2tan of 13 sin(θ-56.3) and I know the maximum is sin inverse of 1 for maximum and sin inverse -1 for minimum but I know the answers are 49,-3 but I don’t know how to get to it any tips ang help much appreciate.

Comment: Its literally unreadable of what you have written!

Comment: $49,-4$ are wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(4 \sin t-6 \cos t)^2-3;\;t\in[0,\pi/2]$$
is maximum at $t=0$ where the value is $33$

to find the minimum, set the derivative $=0$.

$$(4 \sin t-6 \cos t) (6 \sin t+4 \cos t)=0$$

$$4\sin t -6 \cos t=0$$

so the minimum value is
$(4 \sin t-6 \cos t)^2-3=0^2-3=-3$

while $6 \sin t+4 \cos t=0$ is not true in $[0,\pi/2]$

Comment: thank you vwry much

Answer (score 0):

HINT for the maximum: $(4 \sin \theta - 6 \cos \theta)^2-3$ takes its maximum on the interval $(0,90^{\circ})$ at the value of $\theta$ where either:

1. the maximum of $4 \sin \theta - 6 \cos \theta$ is attained in $(0,90^{\circ})$.
2. the minimum of $4 \sin \theta - 6 \cos \theta$ is attained $(0,90^{\circ})$.

Do you see why this is?

In fact eye-balling this, $4 \sin \theta - 6 \cos \theta$  achieves its maximum and its minimum it will achieve at the interval $(0,90^{\circ})$ at the endpoints: $\theta \rightarrow 0$ or $\theta \rightarrow$ $90^{\circ}$. See what you can do with this.

HINT for the minimum: This function takes its global minimum value [at least on the real numbers that is] at $\theta$ for which $4 \sin \theta - 6 \cos \theta =0$. Why is this? Does $4 \sin \theta - 6 \cos \theta$ attain a value of 0 for some $\theta \in (0, 90^{\circ})$?